# Github says "publish" instead of "sync" for private repo

Tags: git, github, synchronization, repository

I want to store my existing projects (say the whole Arduino folder for example) on the git server on my raspberry pi.
So I followed this tutorial (from "Add an Empty Git Repository" title because I already have all above) http://monkeyhacks.com/post/raspberry-pi-as-private-git-server. I can clone from and commit to server just fine. I can also drag and drop the cloned folder on GitHub desktop application. However, on the original existing folder on my local machine which I used for the initial commit, when I drag&drop the folder on GitHub, the "sync" button says "publish" and there are two different branches which is something I did not intend to make. And in this original folder, I cannot commit, sync or anything using github application.

I think I am missing something (git newbie). Do I have to clone the repository to replace the original folder after every time I create a repo on the server? Or is there a more proper way to do this?

Comment: Can you share screenshot of your GitHub Desktop app? And output from `git remote -v` in this repo.

Comment: here's the screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mp7b1v591c8fdey/Screenshot%20%28188%29.png?dl=0
Output from git remote -v is:
origin  mufa@XXXXXX.com:/home/mufa/Arduino (fetch)
origin  mufa@XXXXXX.com:/home/mufa/Arduino (push)

Comment: Are you sure that you set up correct directory in GitHub Desktop? Seems it doesn't see any remotes in your repo. I use following version: `Proctional Fungramming (3.0.15.0) 803d421` and don't see such issues.

Comment: Very sorry for super-late reply. Unfortunately, my laptop got burned (lol, seriously, it got burned). So I guess I will have to wait until i get a new one and recover my data. I don't remember how exactly my set up was.